# Server Side AsyncPattern to call SQL Server

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wcf-data-services

I try to implement the 'AsyncPattern' within a WCF data service. I define the 2 methods BeginGetExperiments(...) and EndGetExperiments(...) in the interface and implement the methods as can be seen below.

```
public class GmdProfileService : IGmdProfileService
{
 IAsyncResult IGmdProfileService.BeginGetExperiments(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        //IAsyncResult res =  Experiment.GetExperimentsAsync(callback, state, Properties.Settings.Default.gmdConnectionString);
        //return res;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Properties.Settings.Default.gmdConnectionString);
        csb.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, name, comment, date, doi FROM tf.TagList WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE proprietary=0;";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        return new SqlCommandAsyncResult(cmd, callback, state);
    }

    public List<Experiment> EndGetExperiments(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        List<Experiment> res = new List<Experiment>();
        SqlCommandAsyncResult myresult = result as SqlCommandAsyncResult;
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = myresult.cmd.EndExecuteReader(myresult.originalState as IAsyncResult))
        {
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    res.Add(new Experiment(reader));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Closing the reader also closes the connection, because this reader was created using the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection value.
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

BeginGetExperiments returns a class `SqlCommandAsyncResult` implementing the `IAsyncResult` interface in addition to holding a reference to my `SqlCommand` for later access.

```
public class SqlCommandAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    public SqlCommand cmd { get; private set; }
    public IAsyncResult originalState { get; private set; }

    public SqlCommandAsyncResult(SqlCommand cmd, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        this.cmd = cmd;
        this.originalState = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(callback,
            state,
            System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess |  // doesn't load whole column into memory
            System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection   // close connection immediately after read
            );
    }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return originalState.AsyncState; }
    }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { return originalState.AsyncWaitHandle; }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(0); }
    }
}
```

The difficulties I face are in the `EndGetExperiments` method. I dont know how to access the `SqlCommand` to call `EndExecuteReader(...)`.
Normally I would use the state object in the `BeginExecutereader` to pass on the command. But if I do so, I get the exception:
"IAsyncResult's State must be the state argument passed to your Begin call."

So I try to use the IAsyncResult to pass the SqlCommand forward to `EndGetExperiments`. Here, the point I don’t understand is that in `EndGetExperiments` the variable result is either of type `IAsyncResult` or of type `SqlCommandAsyncResult` depending on the value of `CompletedSynchronously` in the `SqlCommandAsyncResult` class.
Setting `CompletedSynchronously = false` makes my code fail because I cant't access the SqlCommand whereas setting `CompletedSynchronously = true` the code works like a charm but I have an odd feeling that something might go wrong under the hood.

I appreciate any help, guidance and example code how to make this code working and even more important in helping me to understand the problem at hand.

Thank you very much.
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today WCF Data Services doesn't support asynchronous processing on the server. Please vote/add a feature request for it here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/topics/72603-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 4.0. This might be easier using `Task<T>` to achieve. `Task<T>` is to execute `Func<T>` where T is the return value. You can define a continuation task which fetch Parent.Result. I know this answer might not be what you are looking for. But please consider this as an alternative. The code will be cleaner, easy to maintain, and easy to debug (using Task Parallel Window, Parallel Stacks etc).

Comment: Thank you @tonyjy for your input, but would your suggested pattern be compatible with the BeginMyMethod(...) EndMyMethod(...) pattern in `[OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]` wcf data services?

Comment: I guess it will depend on which goal you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to achieve that your client run without blocking while calling to WCF. The server can be be implemented as synchronous and the client can use be asynchronous. Task<T> will be very useful on the client side, either TreadPool or ConcurrentContext.

Comment: thanks again. I'm confused. The code I posted above is clearly running on the server side. What I try to figure out is how to implement the **server side** of a wcf data service using best practice technologies to fetch some data from a SQl server and then forward them to the client. I try to follow the `AsyncPattern=true` presented here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx). So far, I'm only talking about the server side.

Comment: Okay. Maybe this post can help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/02/09/scale-wcf-application-better-with-asynchronous-programming.aspx